# List(integer) from and to / Min and Max

Tags: views

I have a field as a List(integer) which collects the users height.

```
0|4ft 4in - 132cm
1|4ft 5in - 134cm
2|4ft 6in - 137cm
3|4ft 7in - 139cm
4|4ft 8in - 142cm
5|4ft 9in - 144cm
6|4ft 10in - 147cm
7|4ft 11in - 149cm
etc....
```

But now I am looking to filter users with a from and to in views, which in principle should be simple, but the views option is not there. I would expect to see the normal "Is greater than or equal to" operators normally associated with an integer, but this is not the case with a list(integer).

Below is the screenshot for the operators of a normal integer:
[image: This is the operators for a normal integer]

How do I setup a From and To for height?
Either using the existing List(integer) field or by another means.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like list fields use the "Many to One" views filter, not really sure what the reasoning is, maybe due to having labels the integer values were maybe assumed to not be useful for comparative purposes? I dunno.

Anyway, using the hook_field_views_data_alter() in a custom module, you could swap the filter ID used for your specific field. Example below, you'd need to replace "FIELDNAME_value" with something like "field_int_list_value" if your field name was "field_int_list"

```
use Drupal\field\FieldStorageConfigInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_field_views_data_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_field_views_data_alter(array &$data, FieldStorageConfigInterface $field_storage) {
  foreach ($data as $table_name => $table_data) {
    foreach ($table_data as $field_name => $field_data) {
      if (isset($field_data['filter']) && $field_name === 'FIELDNAME_value') {
        $data[$table_name][$field_name]['filter']['id'] = 'numeric';
      }
    }
  }
}
```